# Javascript to update a UL field

Tags: javascript, html-lists

How can I get js to insert a value to the following UL id autocomplete

I have so far tried, but no progress:

```
document.getElementById("autocomplete").value=output[6];
```

and

```
var item = document.getElementById("autocomplete").childNodes[0];
item.replaceChild(output[6], item.childNodes[0])
```

**Html**:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="containing-element-1">
    <legend class="ui-block-a padding"><b>Site:</b></legend>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><ul id="autocomplete" name="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="..." data-filter-theme="f"></ul></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" id="contractor_list_div"><select name="contractor_list" id="list_contractor" data-mini="true" class="inputreq contractor_wide"></select></div>                      
</div>
```

Comment: Change your ul to input element type

Comment: changing it to an input will require additional work

Comment: UL is normally append li . It is the correct usage , not value

Comment: Do you want a value attribute added to the UL or text displayed inside the UL?

Comment: ended up chamging to input, this required additional work. but worked at the end